# user authentication on heroku with play framework

Tags: heroku, playframework

What is the best way to create user authentication with play framework on heroku? Because both are stateless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [secure module](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/guide8).

If you want to build yourself, then on authentication, store something in the session cookie to show the user is logged in (I usually store userId). The session cookie is secure, so can't be hacked, and keeps everything stateless. Remember that the contents of the cookie can be read, it just can't be modified without corrupting the cookie.

Comment: And if I had to share info between webdyno what is the best way to do it?

Comment: if you need to store any state server side, then you would normally do this by putting the data in a database, and then deleting the data at the end of the process.

Answer (score 0):

> if you need to store any state server side, then you would normally do this by putting the data in a database, and then deleting the data at the end of the process.

Don't forget about caching. For multiple threads/dynos, you can use memcached to access shared cached data. Heroku even mentions it in their great talk: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Horizontal-Scalability